# SvnExeption throw "Disk I/O error"

Tags: c#, svn

I have this error:

When i do checkout in svn, using svnclient (in c#), throw an exception(svnexception).

The message: "disk I/O error".

The problem is that a lot of files are downloaded.

Anyone knows what is this ?

Comment: Have you tried to checkout this repository into another machine?

Comment: Yes, of course, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your machine has some problem with the Hard Disk.

Try to <kbd>Checkout</kbd> the repository in another disk or another machine.